# Mostrar una columna cada vez que se dé scroll javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

- Tengo varias columnas en html
- Cuando cargue la página quiero que solo me muestre la primera
- Cuando el usuario haga scroll muestre la segunda y oculte la primera
- Si vuelve a dar scroll muestre la tercera y oculte la segunda
- Así sucesivamente con todas las columnas.
- Ahora si el usuario da scroll hacia arriba que muestre la columna anterior y vaya ocultando las útltimas (lo contrario a lo anterior)
- Así sucesivamente hasta llegar a la primera.

¿Alguna idea?, Gracias de antemano.

Esto es lo que estoy creando:

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.row2,.row3').hide();
    });
    var cargar = function() {
        var $scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
         if ($scrollTop >= 1) {
             jQuery('.row1').hide();
             jQuery('.row2').fadeIn();
             $scrollTop = 0;
         }
    }
    jQuery(window).on('scroll', cargar);
```

```html
<div class="row1">
 <div class="col6">
     <img src="../img.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col6">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row2">
 <div class="col6">
     <img src="../img.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col6">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row3">
 <div class="col6">
     <img src="../img.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col6">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**¿Cual era el fallo?**

Como tu lo querías hacer era con el evento del scroll. Pero ese evento solo se ejecuta cuando la barra la lateral (que en CSS es la propiedad `overflow`) se mueve. Para que se mueva tiene que estar visible.

**¿Como funciona esta script?**

Ejecuta un evento de la rueda del ratón, he utilizado en mi caso el `.addEventListener("wheel")` aunque también se podría utilizar el `.bind("mousewheel")`
Luego para comprobar si esta haciendo scroll hacia arriba o hacia abajo, utilizo el `event.deltaY` que devolverá **100** si haces scroll hacia abajo o **-100** si haces scroll hacia arriba.

He añadido un limitador para que solo se pueda llamar 1 vez simultáneamente al script (por si da futuros fallos de cuando haces scroll rápidamente), también he añadido el delimitador para que se pase de elementos (si estas en el elemento `row1` que no pueda ir al elemento `row0` o `row-1`...), tanto máximo como mínimo.

Para identificar el elemento actualmente activo he añadido la clase `active` un container con el **id** `row_container` y a todos los elementos les he añadido la clase `row` para que sea más fácil acceder al conjunto de todos los elementos

```js
var animando;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".row1").addClass("active");
    jQuery('.row2,.row3').hide();
    animando=false;
    
 });
    $("#row_container")[0].addEventListener("wheel",function(event){
      var y=event.deltaY;
      var row_n= parseInt($(".row.active").attr("class").split(" ")[1].substr(-1));
      if(animando==false){
        if(y==-100){
          //Scroll hacia arriba
          if($("#row_container .row").length>row_n){
            animando=true;
            var row_desti="#row_container .row"+(row_n+1);
            $(".row.active").hide();
            console.log(row_desti);
            $(row_desti).fadeIn(function(){
              animando=false;
              $(".row.active").removeClass("active");
              $(row_desti).addClass("active");
            });
          }
        }else if(y==100){
          //Scroll hacia abajo
          if(row_n > 1){
            animando=true;
            var row_desti="#row_container .row"+(row_n-1);
            $(".row.active").hide();
            console.log(row_desti);
            $(row_desti).fadeIn(function(){
              animando=false;
              $(".row.active").removeClass("active");
              $(row_desti).addClass("active");
            });
          }
        }else{
          console.log("Scroll error");
        }
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="row_container">
  <div class="row row1">
    <div class="col6">
        <img src="../img.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col6">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row row2">
    <div class="col6">
        <img src="../img.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col6">
          <p>gsasdfgasdLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row row3">
    <div class="col6">
        <img src="../img.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col6">
          <p>ssraLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola que tal, en realidad funciona muy bién, solo hice un pequeño cambio en las condicionales, así:

if ( y >=1 ) 
y
if ( y <=0 ). Muchas gracias!